# Apache CXF 2.3 to 3.0 migration ... where is ServletTransportFactory?

Tags: apache, migration, cxf

I'm trying to migrate from CXF 2.3 to CXF 3.0.3, and found [this 2.3 class](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory) is no longer in 3.0.3's [`cxf-rt-transports-http`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-3.0.x/org/apache/cxf/transport/servlet/package-summary.html) project:

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory
```

**Question**: where is the class (or its alternative) in 3.0.3?

The xml snippet is:

```
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory"
  id="org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory">
    <property name="bus" ref="cxf"/>
    <property name="transportIds">
        <list>
            <value>http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat</value>
            <value>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http</value>
            <value>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/</value>
            <value>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http</value>
            <value>http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/</value>
          <value>http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration</value>                
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: the [official migration doc](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html) does not mention the class

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about the changes of the transport factories in version 2.4.0:

http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/04/14/Introducing+the+unified+http+transport+available+in+CXF+2.4.0